# Paypal api - need a payments pro account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, stripe-payments

Is is possible to send payment via the api without signing up for the Payments Pro account? The £20 per month charge seems a bit expensive just to send a payment when stripe do it without a monthly charge. What are the options when sending cash to a paypal account via a form on my website? I am tied to Paypal as it is the preference of the client.

There are only going to be a few payments per month, for not a lot of cash but it needs to be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

The only API that requires Payments Pro is DoDirectPayment.  All of the other APIs can be used without Pro.