# PayPal API - Payments Pro Required To Process Billing Methods Directly?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

It is my intention to integrate payment processing/subscription billing plans into a site using PHP and Javascript. I'd like to use PayPal to process credit/debit and PayPal charges. I read an article that said (Paraphrasing)

> Normally you have to forward users to PayPal where they input their
>   billing information. PayPal Payments Pro allows you to process billing
>   info directly from your site.

I've also seen information to the contrary. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539301/paypal-api-need-a-payments-pro-account) for instance. Also, the PayPal API docs don't say anything about needing Payments Pro to process a card directly from my site. [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-agreement/) you can see a card being processed without sending the user to PayPal under "Create billing agreement (credit card)."

I have a PayPal business account. I was able to generate a PayPal API Signature (API creds). Can I use the code shown in that quick start to process payment methods without applying for Payments Pro? I'm not talking about IPN. I know that anyone can use that.

Comment: I'm currently walking through all this myself. From what I'm finding, you need one of two things: 1. Payments Pro (which uses PayFlow), or 2. Call PayPal and have them set up "direct billing" on your account. #1 is the newer method, so that's why you have to call in for #2. The documentation and examples that say otherwise are outdated, I think.

Comment: Quote modified into quote.